# After changing URL for the maven local repository, maven stops to work

Tags: maven, cmd, repository, maven-archetype

I have changed the local repository to another disk, settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-
    1.0.0.xsd">

    <localRepository>d:/frameworks/maven36.rep</localRepository>
</settings>
```

Also, I moved the content of the old repository to the new one.
After that, if I am trying to create the simple project by:

```
mvn -X archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.packt.cookbook -DartifactId=simple-project -DarchetypeArtifactId=mavenarchetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

, I am getting:

```
Failure to find org.apache.maven.archetypes:mavenarchetype-quickstart
```

I have tried two versions of -DarchetypeVersion, the current 1.4 or default 1.0. Did not help.
All solutions that I found on the SO are 1) about Eclipse, and 2) tell how to return to the default maven settings. But I don't want to return to the default settings. I need my local repository to be on another disk.

What is interesting, if I don't reference to the archetypeArtifact precisely, and try to create the project this way:

```
mvn -X archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.packt.cookbook -DartifactId=simple-project -DinteractiveMode=false
```

, it works. But I am afraid that in the further work with maven some other usual calls won't work, too. For example, I still cannot use the "traditional" creation, due to the same problem.

***As far as I understand, my new local repository simply lacks some necessary files. How can I load them there?***

The problem is that all sites that say how to change the URL for the local repository don't say a word about what else should I do after changing the URL in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you usually don't need to do anything after changing the path of the local repository. If you copy the files over, this should be fine, but otherwise they are drawn again from the remote repositories you specified.

You have a typo in your question that might be the cause of your trouble:

`mavenarchetype-quickstart` does not exist. It is `maven-archetype-quickstart`.